# % vs. + as related to strings in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

This:

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

print joke_evaluation % hilarious
```

and this:

> w = "This is the left side of..." e = "a string with a right side."
>
> print w + e

Seem to be doing the same thing. Why can't I change the code to read:

```
print joke_evaluation + hilarious
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: That's because you can only concatenate a string to another string, while `False` is a bool type here. I'd prefer `format()` over `%` based string formatting.

Comment: Ok. I'm still way new so I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6):

`%r` calls `repr()`, which represents `False` (bool) as `"False"` (string).

`+` can only be used to concatenate a string with other strings (Otherwise you get a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects`)

You can convert `False` to a string before you concatenate it:

```
>>> print "Isn't that joke so funny?!" + str(False)
```

You could also try new string formatting:

```
>>> print "Isn't that joke so funny?! {!r}".format(False)
Isn't that joke so funny?! False
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a type conversion issue.  When you are trying to concatenate to a string in Python, you may only concatenate other strings.  You are attempting to concatenate a Boolean value to a string, which is not a supported operation.

You could do

```
print w + str(e)
```

and that would be functional.

Comment: in his particular case `%r` will make it repr(e), `"%r" % "a"` will result in `"'a'"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what was confusing me:

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"

print joke_evaluation % hilarious
```

I would prefer it to look like this:

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r" % hilarious

print joke_evaluation
```

I guess it just looked funky to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This was quite confusing to me as well, but it seems that due to it being a Boolean value you cannot use +.

If you do you get an error like this:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects
```